# Parse display images in collectionView

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a tableView with a CollectionView inside, in the TableView is the users details and I am trying to put the images belonging to the user in the collectionView.

So far I have everything working correctly apart from the images are not correct. Every image uploaded is displaying for each user, I need match the images to the user...I have been trying for a while now and have not found a solution so I'm hoping someone can help me here!

Here is my query for getting the user details and images:

```
 func loadPosts() {


        let followQuery = PFQuery(className: "Follows")
        followQuery.whereKey("follower", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
        followQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock ({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.followArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                for object in objects! {
                    self.followArray.append(object.valueForKey("following") as! String)

                }

                self.followArray.append(PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
                let query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
                query.whereKey("usernamee", containedIn: self.followArray)
                query.addDescendingOrder("createdAt")

                query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        self.usernameArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                        self.imageArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
                        self.uuidArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

                        for object in objects! {

  self.usernameArray.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String)
  self.imageArray.append(object.valueForKey("imageArray") as! PFFile)
  self.uuidArray.append(object.valueForKey("uuid") as! String)

                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                        } else {

                        print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    }
                })
            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        })

    }
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues I see in your code. First of all, in your `Posts` query, you use the `whereKey()` method: `query.whereKey("usernamee", containedIn: self.followArray)`. `username` is spelled incorrectly, and this may be causing some issues. In addition, you remove all objects from your array every time you issue a query. There must be some way to add and remove data as necessary. (This only applies if you are refreshing data. If you have not added data to the arrays, there is no need to empty them.) Finally, you have a value called `imageArray` that is stored as a `PFFile`. An array would be multiple objects. It is hard to tell whether or not each user has multiple images or not. (For the solution, I assume that there is only one image per user. I would suggest changing the name of the key to be more precise. If this is not the case, write me a comment.)

Now, in regards to your actual problem, I believe that this is because you have only one array for all the images, and when you display it for each user, the entire array is used. In order to correct for this, I would suggest building a data structure in the following format: `[(String, Image)]`, where `String` is the `username` and `Image` is file for the image. You can thus access the users and their images as an array of tuples.

To create the array of tuples, I would suggest: `var usersAndImagesArray = [(username: String, imageFile: PFFile)]()`

To add to the array:

```
for object in objects!{
    usersAndImagesArray.append(object.valueForKey("username") as! String, object.valueForKey("image") as! PFFile)
}
```

To access the values when setting up the cells:

```
let username = usersAndImagesArray[index.row].username
let imageFile = usersAndImagesArray[index.row].imageFile
```

Comment: Hello and wow, I wasn't expecting such an answer with all that information! About what you mentioned at the begining about adding and removing necessary data, I'm pretty sure you're correct and I will look into it...I followed several tutorials on udemy to learn Parse so I don't know too much! Regarding my problem I tried your solution but nothing has seemed to change unfortunately, I have taken two sceenshots so you can see how I set it all up! CollectionView: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5b9rv.png   & Query: http://i.stack.imgur.com/nYX4t.png Ps. I need to fix "usernamee" in Parse column!!

Comment: And about "Array would be multiple objects", you're correct there too. It can vary there might be 5 images or none at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You said that you have a separate collection view for each row in the table view. In order to get only the images for each user, you need to create a variable that will store the `index.row` of the table view, not the collection view. I was unclear. It should be something like: `var indexOfTableViewRow: Int` and `file = usersAndImagesArray[indexOfTableViewRow].imageFile`

Comment: I have a collectionView in a tableViewCell, which is repeated depending on the amount of users. And in that collectionView is a cell which displays the images of that user being displayed. Would I add what you put above in the comment to my tableView cellForRow...?

Comment: No. The other way around. The line should go in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` with the index from the row in the table view cell.

Comment: Ok, starting to understand now..Last thing about that comment, Int and file, should that be int || file(or PFFile?)

Comment: If I understand your question, they should be two separate lines of code. One is a way to declare the variable, and the other is the way to access the image, or array of images from `usersAndImagesArray`.

Comment: Hmm, if you like we can go into the chat and I'll try and explain my self better, and then we'll be sure if we're doing the right thing here

Comment: We can't you currently don't have enough reputation. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104802/discussion-between-acoop-and-jack).